# How to convert unicode F1 emojis for use in telegram

Tags: javascript, unicode

I can't get all emojis to display correctly and as it seems

While any unicode starting with 1F is not accepted by javascript.
\1F21A

This seems to work
\u26a0

How to get the ones starting with 1F to work?

```
slimbot.sendMessage('-xxxxx', ` \u1f4c8`)
```

Comment: Can you provide the code you tried please ?

Comment: [String.fromCodePoint](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCodePoint)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for the `\u{1f4c80}` escape sequence, which allows arbitrary codepoints not just 4-digit charcodes like `\u1234`.